# Trying to import wget libraries but it's not happening why? It says requirement satisfied but not able to import it. Giving module not found error

Tags: python-3.x, wget

```
 get_ipython().system('pip install wget')
    import wget
    Requirement already satisfied: wget in
          c:\users\divya\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (3.2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[9], line 2
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install wget')
----> 2 import wget

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'
```

I tried re-downloading it but nothing seems to work to import the library. There were some solutions which asked to check the version of python it was the third version. Python installed on my computer is the third version.
`

Comment: Have you tried `!pip install wget`?

Comment: "Python installed on my computer is the third version": if you mean Python 3: there are many of those, so it would need to be more specific. But more importantly is where the location of the Python executable is, and whether that corresponds to the  `pip` executable used.

Comment: Check `sys.executable`, for example.

Comment: Why are you installing wget inside of python code? How did you start the python that you're running?